# What is a "functional model" in the context of model operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I'm reading a survey paper on model spaces, there is written "the study can therefore be restricted to CNU operators, which with some additional hypotheses obtain concrete a functional model"
What is a "functional model"?

Googleing donst help since this seem to be a well used term in alot of subjects and I cant understand it from Nagy and Foias book which it in the references.
I have and idea that it would be some kind of functional calculus but Im not really sure.

I understand that one can "model" some contractions as restrictions of the shift to $\phi H^{2}$ where $\phi$ is inner but I fail to see how this would be related to some functional calculus.

Comment: You mean what "is" ?

Comment: What are CNU operators?

Comment: @TrialAndError completely nonunitary contractions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\|A\| < 1$. You can take limits of $rA$ as $r\uparrow 1$ for a general contraction $A$, which makes the following construction generally useful for any $A\in\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$ for $\|A\| \le 1$, though the limiting case involves an positive operator measure on the unit circle $\mathbb{T}=\partial D$, which is the boundary of the unit disk $D$.

If $f$ is holomorphic on a neighborhood of the closed unit disk $D$, then, for $|z| < 1$, the following reflection argument comes from the Poisson integral representation:
\begin{align}
     f(A) & = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\partial D}\frac{f(w)}{w I-A}dw \\
         & = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\partial D}f(w)\left[\frac{1}{wI-A}-\frac{A^*}{w A^*-I}\right]dw \\
   & =\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\partial D}f(w)\left[\frac{1}{wI-A}+\frac{\overline{w}A^*}{\overline{w}I-A^*}\right]dw \\
   & =\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\partial D}f(w)\frac{1}{\overline{w}I-A^*}\left[(\overline{w}I-A^*)+\overline{w}A^*(wI-A)\right]\frac{1}{wI-A}dw \\
  & =\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\partial D}f(w)\frac{1}{\overline{w}I-A^*}(I-A^*A)\frac{1}{wI-A}\overline{w}dw.
\end{align}
Let $\sigma$ be the normalized Lebesgue measure on the unit circle, and let $|B|=\sqrt{B^*B}$. Then
$$
         f(A) = \int_{\partial D}f(w)\left|\sqrt{I-A^*A}\frac{1}{wI-A}\right|^2d\sigma(w).
$$
In particular, for $n=0,1,2,3,\cdots$,
\begin{align}
         A^n & = \int_{\partial D}w^n\left|\sqrt{I-A^*A}\frac{1}{wI-A}\right|^2d\sigma(w) \\
        (A^*)^n & = \int_{\partial D}\overline{w}^n\left|\sqrt{I-A^*A}\frac{1}{wI-A}\right|^2d\sigma(w).
\end{align}
You can define a new Hilbert space $\mathcal{K}$ as the closure of polynomials in $w,\overline{w}$ on $T$ with vector coefficients. For such a polynomial,
$$
           p(w,\overline{w})=p_{-n}\overline{w}^n+\cdots+p_{-1}\overline{w}+p_0+p_1 w+\cdots+p_{n}w^{n},\;\; p_j \in \mathcal{H},
$$
define an inner product through the norm
$$
     \|p\|_{\mathcal{K}}^2 = \int_{\partial D}\left\|\,\left|\sqrt{I-A*A}\frac{1}{wI-A}\right|p(w,\overline{w})\,\right\|^2d\sigma(w).
$$
Define a map $V : \mathcal{H}\rightarrow\mathcal{K}$ so that $Vx$ is the constant polynomial $p(w,\overline{w})=x$. Then
$$
              \|Vx\|_{\mathcal{K}}=\|x\|_{\mathcal{H}},\;\;\; x\in\mathcal{H}.
$$
Let $M : \mathcal{K}\rightarrow\mathcal{K}$ be defined by $(Mp)(w,\overline{w})=wp(w,\overline{w})$. Then $M$ is unitary, and
$$
                 (M^n Vx,Vy)_{\mathcal{K}}= (A^nx,y)_{\mathcal{H}},\;\;\; x,y\in \mathcal{H} \\
        V^*M^nV = A^n,\;\;\; n=0,1,2,3,\cdots.
$$

Comment: wow this is very involved. It looks like some kind of functional calculus, which are contaning definitions of functionals on the hilbert space (second to last line). I have a hard time understanding the advantanges or implications of such a calculus compated to the seemingly less involved once. Why do we want $(A^nx,y) $ for instance?

Comment: @User1 : The operator $M$ is unitary, and is known as a unitary 'dilation' of the contraction $A$. An arbitrary bounded $A$ with $\|A\|\le 1$ can be viewed as a unitary operator, and all positive powers of $A$ correspond to the same powers of $M$. This is what Nagy and Foias consider. There are various ways to get at this 'functional calculus.' The one I've given you is constructive.

Comment: Its there a nice abstact formulation of your answer aswell?

Comment: @User1 : The abstract formulation is: Let $A$ be an operator on a complex Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ with $\|A\| \le 1$. Then there exists a larger Hilbert space $\mathcal{K}$ and a unitary operator $M$ on $\mathcal{K}$ such that $A^n$ is the restriction of $M^n$ to $\mathcal{H}$ for all $n=1,2,3,\cdots$. The operator $M$ is the 'unitary dilation' of $A$. The operator $M$ and space $\mathcal{K}$ are essentially unique when defined correctly.

Comment: Im sorry for all the extra questions but is the "$H^{\infty}$-calculus" a special case of this? By taking the hilbert space to be $H^2$ and $A \in H^{\infty}$ and if so can anything be said about $M$ and $\mathcal{K}$ then? My guess would be the shift and some invariant subspace for the shift.

Comment: @User1 : There is a sense in what you wrote is true. The dilation $M$ is mulplication by $z$ on vector polynomials in $z$, but closed under a non-standard norm.